# Accessing axios reponse outside of axios.post

Tags: reactjs, axios

**I am trying to read the response from Axios.post into a new variable outside of the Axios.post. However it keeps reading as undefined**

```
var newresults 
 axios.post(mainurl, data)
        .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
newresults = response
console.log(newresults)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
const postData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post(mainurl, data);
  console.log(response);
};

postData();
```